# Issue with signup page using clean swift architecture in Xcode

Tags: swift, clean-architecture

I am currently implementing a signup feature into a chat application I am working on. In my 'SignupViewController' I want to implement a function named 'signupButtonPressed' which routes me from a signup viewcontroller to a 'ListContacts' viewcontroller. If the signup fails, then a function called 'showValidationError' will execute. Code excerpt from my SignupViewController below:

```
@IBAction func signupButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let request = Signup.Request(
    name: fullNameTextField.text!,
    email: emailTextField.text!,
    password: passwordTextField.text!
    )

    interactor?.createAccount(request: request)   
}

func showValidationError(_ message: String) {
    let alertCtrl = UIAlertController(title: "Oops! An error occurred", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertCtrl.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.show(alertCtrl, sender: self)
}
```

I am using Swift Clean Architecture, so I will link the code to my Signup Router, Model, and Interactor files also:

1) Signupinteractor.swift:

```
import Foundation

protocol SignupBusinessLogic {
    func createAccount(request: Signup.Request)
}

class SignupInteractor: SignupBusinessLogic {
    var viewController: SignupFormErrorLogic?
    var router: (NSObjectProtocol & SignupRoutingLogic)?
    var worker = UsersWorker()

    func createAccount(request: Signup.Request) -> Void {
        self.worker.signup(request: request) { user, error in

            guard error == nil else {

               print(error!)
                self.viewController?.showValidationError("Error creating account!")
                return
            }

            self.router?.routeToListContacts()
        }
    }
}
```

2) SignupModels.swift:

```
import Foundation

enum Signup {
    struct Request {
        var name: String
        var email: String
        var password: String
    }

    struct Response {
        var user: User?

        init(data: [String:Any]) {
            self.user = User(
                id: data["id"] as! Int,
                name: data["name"] as! String,
                email: data["email"] as! String,
                chatkit_id: data["chatkit_id"] as! String
            )
        }
    }
}
```

3) SignupRouter.swift:

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol SignupRoutingLogic {
    func routeToListContacts()
}

class SignupRouter: NSObject, SignupRoutingLogic {
    weak var viewController: SignupViewController?

    func routeToListContacts() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigator") as! UINavigationController

        viewController!.show(destinationVC, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

The signup function in my UsersWorker.swift file:

```
func signup(request: Signup.Request, completionHandler: @escaping (User?, UsersStoreError?) -> Void) {
    let params: Parameters = [
        "name": request.name,
        "email": request.email,
        "password": request.password
    ]

    postRequest("/api/users/signup", params: params, headers: nil) { data in
        guard data != nil else {
            return completionHandler(nil, UsersStoreError.CannotSignup)
        }

        let response = Signup.Response(data: data!)
        CurrentUserIDDataStore().setID(CurrentUserID(id: response.user?.chatkit_id))

        let request = Login.Account.Request(
            email: request.email,
            password: request.password
        )

        self.login(request: request) { token, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return completionHandler(nil, UsersStoreError.CannotLogin)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(response.user, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter signup details into the signup UITextfields (fullNameTextField; emailTextField; passwordTextField) and press the signup button, an error called 'CannotSignup' triggers. Unsure why however. This case can also be found in my UsersWorker.swift file:

```
enum UsersStoreError: Error {
    case CannotLogin
    case CannotSignup
    case CannotFetchChatkitToken
}
```

Would be great if anyone is able to look over the code to get an idea for what the issue might be, and how I might resolve it? If any further info is required just ask!

Comment: Since you enter this block `return completionHandler(nil, UsersStoreError.CannotSignup)`, seems like `data` at that point is `nil`, meaning that your `postRequest` is failing. Can you trace the resposnse of that call?

Comment: here's the response

FAILURE: responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 500))
CannotSignup

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the API call is failing, Please make a check on return HTTP status code instead of `data`. In some cases the API call can be success without any response data
Ideally send an `Error` instance as well along with data back from `postRequest` method

Comment: here's the response FAILURE: responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 500))

Comment: 500 means Server error, something is broken in the api. You just need to catch the error and show it nicely to the user. May be something like "Unable to process, Please try again later!"